# How to configure Waveshare 7 inch display for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: display

I need help to configure display settings.
My config.txt is set by default.
Any clue? Thank you!

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=0

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

[image]

Comment: waveshare sell at least 5 different 7" displays for the raspberry pi, each with there own **[wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Main_Page)** for instructions on how to use them - all of them as far as I can tell require changes to at least `config.txt` - so, a "standard" `config.txt` (not sure why you even bothered to post that since it's the standard one, that everybody here would already be aware of) won't work

Comment: Sorry for a not-so-warm welcome, but questions which have typos for the root cause are not accepted by the site rules. They are pretty useless to future readers who will likely make a typo elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)

But be careful the official wiki has following config text:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

**There is an error here**

**hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0 must be hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 6 0 0 0**

The equal sign is missing here!

So the correct text is

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```